# setTimeout not working as expected

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a for loop in Javascript. The desired goal is to print out 0, 1, 2 with a 3 second gap in between.

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

This prints everything out as expected, with no pause. But when I add in a setTimeout:

```
for (var i=0; i<3; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {console.log{i},3000*i}
}
```

The result is that it prints out `3`, `3`, `3` with a 3 second gap. The pause worked, but it looks like its completing the loop before the right numbers can get printed.

Comment: Do a search on JavaScript closures.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-do-javascript-closures-work

Comment: The loop isn't waiting for the `timeout` to run, so by the time it does run, the loop is done and `i` is 3. You don't need a loop, just `var i=0; setTimeout(function() { console.log(i); i++; },3000*i);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're exactly right that the loop is getting completed before the `setTimeout` calls run. Since all of your timeout functions reference `i`, they're all going to print out `3`. The way to fix this is to capture the *value* of `i` in a closure.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  (function(index) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log(index);
    }, 3000 * index);
  })(i); // Instantly call the function and pass the value of i
}
```

Comment: Or you could use the `.bind()` method -> http://jsfiddle.net/jb9pd5ub/

Comment: @JoshCrozier That would definitely work as well.

Comment: I'm new to Javascript and had a follow up question. The context is that I have a list of URL's that I want to click (but not all at the same time, and thus the pause). How do I set `index` and what do you mean `Instantly call the function and pass the value of i`? That part didn't make sense to me.

Comment: btw, this works, but I don't understand how `index` is getting set to the value of `i` and what `(i)` is doing :-)

Comment: `(i)` is the argument of the "immediately invoked function expression", that means you ar calling `(function(index) { ..... }` with parameter `i`. The value of index (i) is then preserved within the local scope of the function passed to the setTimeout, the closure.